# how to convert capture a image from webcam in Image<Hsv, Byte> format ?

Tags: c#, opencv, type-conversion, gesture

I am doing the following code .  Is there a way to convert Image `<bgr,Byte>` to Image `<hsv,Byte>`?

```
Image<Hsv, Byte> imgOriginal;
Image<Hsv, Byte> imgRed;    
imgOriginal = capWebCam.QueryFrame();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Convert function:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imageA;
Image<Hsv, Byte> imageB;
imageB = imageA.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();
```